# How do I create a matrix whose elements are the sum of the row and column numbers?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I need to create a 95x95 matrix in MATLAB in which each element is a sum of its row and column number.
I'm new at this so I can't really think of a way to tell MATLAB to just create a matrix without putting the elements in. 
From what I understand I'll have to initiate a loop for the sum part.

Answer (score 8):

No math needed if you use [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html):

```
A = hankel(2:96, 96:190);
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose another strategy, as simple as EitanT's one:

```
  v = 1:95;
  A = bsxfun(@plus,v,v');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need "reinventing the wheel" with loops. Try this:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:95, 1:95);
A = X + Y
```

The desired output is stored in matrix `A`.